# Run nodejs functions from a web server

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm running a web server on raspberry pi and I want to call a node.js function when clicking on a button on a page. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You need to have a Node app listening on some port on your server. The simplest way would be to have a very simple Express app, for example:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.post('/some/path', function (req, res) {
    // call your function here
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

Now, in your HTML you need to make a POST request to http://YOURDOMAIN:3000/some/path to call your function (for example using a form or an AJAX request).

If you're using a webserver like nginx then you can proxy requests to your app so that your app won't have to access under different port and/or domain than your main website.